# Compile error when running a for loop over a range

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code that tries to get a dynamic range and print the values of each cells of the range.

```
Sub Macro3()

'
    Range("D10").Select
    x = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select


    For Each cell In x
        MsgBox (cell)
    Next x

End Sub
```

If I run it however it get a compile error... Any thoughts on what goes wrong here?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Inaccurate reference to variable next (translated from Dutch)

Answer (score 1):

Try this: (use `Set` and remove `.Select`)

```
Set x = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown))
```

and `Next` or `Next cell` instead of `Next x`

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro3()

    Dim x       As Range
    Dim cell    As Range


    Range("D10").Select

    Set x = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    For Each cell In x
        MsgBox (cell)
    Next cell

End Sub
```

Hi. you need next cell and not next x. Enjoy! :D